# VueJS - Why is process.env file not defined in HTML part of Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, environment-variables, vue-component

In the HTML part of the application `process.env` is undefined or not exists.

Example:

`` <img v-if="newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug" :src=" `domain as string` + newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug " /> ``

And this works, but if I set variable in a bind src in HTML part:

`` <img v-if="newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug" :src=" `${process.env.VUE_APP_IMG_ROOT}` + this.newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug " /> ``

`TypeError: can't access property "env", _ctx.process is undefined`

As result `env` not exist.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `process` is available during compilation only, not at runtime.

The recommended way of accessing `env` variables in templates is trough a computed property:

```
<img 
  v-if="newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug" 
  :src=" `${imageRoot}` + this.newsData[0].post[0].featured_image.slug " />

computed: {
  imageRoot(){
    return process.env.VUE_APP_IMG_ROOT
  }
}
```